# 'used to' in a sentence

Tags: phrases

Is it correct to end a sentence with 'used to'?

Ex :

> You have to find a new shop when you are no longer able to go to the shop that you have used to.

or should it be;

> You have to find a new shop when you are no longer able to go to the shop that you have used to go.

Comment: It would be OK to end with 'used to' in casual speech. but 'have' is wrong; it should be just 'you used to'.

Comment: I guess it is an example of the type of *ellipsis* called **pseudogapping** - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)#Pseudogapping

Answer (score 1):

Your question asked whether you could end a sentence with "used to". The answer is "yes", especially in informal speech. However your use of "have" is in error.

> You have to find a new shop when you are no longer able to go to the shop **that you used to**.

Many strict grammarians in the past considered it wrong to end a sentence with a preposition. It was the kind of prescriptive 'rule' that makes little sense in reality. But in formal contexts it may still be advisable to avoid ending sentences with prepositions *if you can do so without creating something cumbersome*.

Adding "go" to the end of the sentence as you have done, does not "fix" the sentence, but introduces an error. "Go" has to have its preposition "to" somewhere, even if you move it away from the end of the sentence. In your sentence "to" has been lost.

To avoid ending the sentence in a preposition you would need to say this:

> You have to find a new shop when you are no longer able to go to the shop **to which you used to go.**

When avoiding ending sentences with prepositions, the construction "to which, from which, on which, under which ..." (etc) is usually required.

As the [oft cited, technically misleading](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001702.html), and [certainly apocryphal](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001715.html) statement made by Winston Churchill* makes clear:

> This is the sort of bloody nonsense up with which I will not put.

insisting on *not* ending sentences in prepositions can get you into cumbersome mess.

(*Quoting Churchill, like Dr Johnson, is the last refuge of the scoundrel.)

Answer (score 0):

In my perspective, i would prefer "used to" instead of have used to since "have used to" can also mean that you are still going to the shop until now

You can go with or without go but i prefer without have and go, to make it more simple